Formulate systemd .link file as plain udev rule or rename network interface without mac address
Due to hardware reasons, we have to rename our network interfaces. Because we have to do that on all our boards, for which we do not know the mac address, we have to do it using the id-path or driver.
We are doing it currently with systemd .link files, which look like this:
[Match]
Path=<path-name>

[Link]
Description=<driver-name>,mainboard
NamePolicy=keep
Name=eth0

Due to legal and software reasons, we have to get rid of systemd. So how can we formulate these files into plain udev rules?
I ended up with this:
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_PATH}=="<path-name>", NAME="eth0"

called it 10-rename-eth0.rules and placed it into /etc/udev/rules.d/, but it did not work.
I also tried to add the following statements to the rule:
ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0",
ATTR{type}=="1",
KERNEL=="end0"

but it still did not work.
I put these rules together from these links:
[solved] Rename network interface without using MAC addresstext
Setting persistent name for usb serial device with udev rule without symlink
Udev : renaming my network interface
and some others and of course I read the udev manpage.
What am I doing wrong?

But udev is a systemd component. (One with a less permissive license than the rest of systemd, for that matter.) If you get rid of systemd, you will not have udev.

(Also, as a general thing, linux.die.net has very outdated manual pages. The udev(8) manual that you found is actually from 2005!)


NAME="eth0"

eth# is already the default kernel-assigned name format. You usually don't need to rename interfaces to eth0 – you'll get the same result by disabling the renaming entirely.
Also, because of that, if you do want to explicitly rename an interface to eth0, keep in mind that udev has no collision avoidance – if there already happens to be another interface named eth0, the renaming will fail.

called it 10-rename-eth0.rules

That runs too early. Udev rules files are sorted alphabetically by filename (in ASCII order), and the rule that produces ENV{ID_PATH} is actually in 50-udev-default.rules:
50-udev-default.rules:
  SUBSYSTEM=="pci|usb|platform", IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"

Your custom rules must therefore be after 50-* for ID_PATH and related properties to be available. A common position for network interface renaming rules is 70-* or 80-*.
(For example, RHEL's "persistent interface name" rules used to be 70-persistent-net.rules, whereas systemd's .link file processing is actually done in 80-net-setup-link.rules.)

Thanks for your answer, I will try that!
Unfortunately our kernel names the devices with 'end#', but our bootloader uses 'eth#' which causes the problems.

had the correct hint. Either your rule comes later (as described in her/his answer) or you enter a IMPORT{buildtin}="path_id" into your rule.
Many thanks
